# How can i embed digital signature in pdf using PDFSharp in c#?

Tags: c#, digital-signature, pdfsharp

Is there any way in PDFSharp to embed the digital signature in pdf file.

Answer (score 2):

An implementation for digital signatures can be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/pull/11

I didn't test it yet, so I don't know if it works, how it works.