# How to set placement of digital signature PDFSharp on the other page?

Tags: c#, pdf, digital-signature, pdfsharp

I was trying to sign a pdf document with a certificate and append the signature after the text on the last page. The tool has to be open-source.

I have encountered a post about the digital signing: [How can i embed digital signature in pdf using PDFSharp in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220148/how-can-i-embed-digital-signature-in-pdf-using-pdfsharp-in-c)

which led me to this repository:
https://github.com/KDS/PDFsharp/tree/ec20c7161aa9dc26889431917c089e6d8c07ab6e/src

As I understood, It is possible to change position of signature in SignatureTestConsole/Program.cs 74

```
65        private static void SignExisting()
66        {
67            string text = string.Format("SignExisting.pdf", new object[0]);
68            PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(new MemoryStream(Resources.doc1));
69            PdfSignatureOptions options = new PdfSignatureOptions
70            {
71                ContactInfo = "Contact Info",
72                Location = "Paris",
73                Reason = "Test signatures",
74                Rectangle = new XRect(36.0, 735.0, 200.0, 50.0),
75                AppearanceHandler = new Program.SignAppearenceHandler()
76            };
77            PdfSignatureHandler pdfSignatureHandler = new PdfSignatureHandler(Program.GetCertificate(), null, options);
78            pdfSignatureHandler.AttachToDocument(pdfDocument);
79            pdfDocument.Save(text);
80            Process.Start(text);
81        }
```

However, I cannot select the page where the signature should be located and the position after the text. The signature appears on the first page and its position has to be set via code.

I was trying to check how the signature appearance is handled, in PdfSignatureField.cs lines 145-173 there is a function PrepareForSave:

```
    internal override void PrepareForSave()
    {
        if (!this.visible)
            return;

        if (this.AppearanceHandler == null)
            throw new Exception("AppearanceHandler is null");



        PdfRectangle rect = Elements.GetRectangle(PdfAnnotation.Keys.Rect);
        XForm form = new XForm(this._document, rect.Size);
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromForm(form);

        this.AppearanceHandler.DrawAppearance(gfx, rect.ToXRect());

        form.DrawingFinished();

        // Get existing or create new appearance dictionary
        PdfDictionary ap = Elements[PdfAnnotation.Keys.AP] as PdfDictionary;
        if (ap == null)
        {
            ap = new PdfDictionary(this._document);
            Elements[PdfAnnotation.Keys.AP] = ap;
        }

        // Set XRef to normal state
        ap.Elements["/N"] = form.PdfForm.Reference;
    }
```

I was trying to change `XGraphics` to

`XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(_document.Pages[_document.Pages.Count - 1]);`

but the sign was always appearing in the corner of last page. Is `XForm form` always representing only first page?

Answer (score 0):

> Is `XForm form` always representing only first page?

An XForm is like a rubber stamp. You can use it many times and on any page where you want to use it.
You show the code that creates the form, but I don't see where it is used.

A sample that uses `XForm` can be found here:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx

Comment: Hi here is the full code using Xgraphics made with XForm in mehod PrepareForSave() mentioned in my main post.  The PrepareForSave() invokes DrawAppearance method https://github.com/KDS/PDFsharp/blob/ec20c7161aa9dc26889431917c089e6d8c07ab6e/src/SignatureTestConsole/Program.cs
The DrawAppearance draws signature in fixed position, what I try to archive is to append the signature right below text on the last page.

Comment: It seems `Rectangle = new XRect(36.0, 735.0, 200.0, 50.0)` specifies the location of the signature. Try different values here, calculated depending on the contents of the page.  
The code that obtains the `XGraphics` object must be somewhere else. Try to find it with the debugger.